# The ordinal 968 issue

Tags: dll, openssl

I am using openssl in a project. It works fine on one machine. However, on an xp pro machine I get:

The ordinal 968 could not be located in hte dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, is it a dependency issue on some other dll?

Answer (score 0):

A Google search leads to a [forum thread](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/505134-solved-libeay32-dll-most-likely.html) where someone solved this problem. This might help you to do so, too.

Answer (score 0):

This Page:

http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Pointed me to this:

Install the c++ 2008 redistributable and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, just with a different number (3906).

When I searched for all `libeay32.dll` files in my `%PATH%`, I noticed that there are quite a few installed on my system. The first in the path happened to be an older version (OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008), installed with Gnuwin32. I renamed this file to `libeay32.dll.xxx`, effectively disabling this dll, and this fixed the issue for me! The next `libeay32.dll` on my path is a much more recent version (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014).

I wrote this little python script to find the libeay32.dll files on my system, and to determine the OpenSSL version:

```
import os, re
for dir in os.getenv("PATH").split(";"):
  filename = os.path.join(dir, "libeay32.dll")
  if os.path.exists(filename):
    print("== " + dir)
    with open(filename, "rb") as fh:
      for line in fh:
        m = re.search("OpenSSL [0-9][0-9. a-zA-Z]+", line)
        if m:
          print(m.group(0))
          break
```